# Prevent hiding clear button on losing focus for input="search"

Tags: html, search, input, focus

I use HTML5

```html
<input type="search" />
```

As soon as one starts typing, the clear button ('x') appears. So far that's what I want. But when the focus is no longer on the input field (although there are still characters inside), the clear button gets hidden.

**How can I prevent that behavior?**

I want to save the user that extra step of having to focus back on the search input to clear it. So the 'x' should be visible as long as there are more than 0 characters in the search input, no matter where the focus is.

Comment: For me in Chrome just hovering over the search box shows the **x** that clears it

Comment: @j08691 first of all, as a user you need to know this and secondly, that doesn't work on touchscreen.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div class="input-container">
            <input class="search" type="search" />
            <span class="clearinput">x</span>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>

$(".search").on("focusin",function(e) {   
$('.clearinput').css('opacity','1');  

    });
    $(".search").on("focusout",function(e) {
      $('.clearinput').css('opacity','0'); 
        });

    $(document).on('click','.clearinput',function(e){

       $('.search').val('');
        });



</script>


 <style>
 .input-container{max-width: 250px;position: relative;}
 .search{    width: 100%;
 z-index:-1;position: absolute; 
    padding-right: 60px;}
 .clearinput{
     position: absolute;z-index:6;
     float: right;
     cursor: pointer;
    right: 10px;
    height: 25px;border:1px solid red;width:25px;font-size:32px;
    background-color:red;
/* display:none; */
    top: 0;}

</style>
```

you can not hide on focus in and out because when we clear the or click the cross button it run focus out then not able to clear the  search fields . make styling according to your sorry for bad styling